# Get rank within table for any number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bidding system in place. The user enters how much he wants to bid, which then sends a request via ajax to a PHP script, which then gets what rank that bid would place under the existing bids, and then displays it back to the bidder. This allows him to increase his bid to get the rank he wants.

For example

```
+-----------+------------+
| bidder_id | bid_amount |
+-----------+------------+
|  1        | 20         |
|  2        | 20         | 
|  3        | 30         |
|  5        | 40         |
|  6        | 10         |
+-----------+------------+
```

The user bids 15$, the query gets the rank as 5th.

How would this query look like? Is is possible to insert a fake row with the new user's bid and then order everything?

Comment: May be duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333665/1399505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this should do it;

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 rank
FROM bids
WHERE bid_amount > 15
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3b21/2).